# show Popup(do you want to save changes?) while row change in grid extjs3

Tags: extjs, extjs3, extjs-grid

want to show popup (like.. Do you want to save changes?) while row change of grid and pop Up have buttons like YES and NO, if previous row is modified and user click on "YES" in popup at that time previous row will be selected till user will not save it  and if user click on "NO" at that time remove previous row changes and select next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing` to edit rows.

You need to listen on [beforeedit](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing.html#event-beforeedit) event and commit/reject the changes with combine with `Ext.Msg.confirm` to prompt.

Like:

```
plugins: [{
    ptype: 'cellediting',
    listeners: {
        beforeedit: function (editor, context) {
            Ext.Msg.confirm("Confirmation", "Confirm to save",
            function (btn) {
                if (btn === "yes") {
                     context.record.commit();
                } else {
                     context.record.reject()
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]
```